# Kohana 2 deleted page warning

Tags: php, database, kohana, kohana-2

I'm using Kohana 2 on my admin panel. But when click Add New button, get Page Not Found warning.

Its warning:

```
The requested page was not found. It may have moved, been deleted, or archived.

panel/system/core/Kohana.php [842]:

The page you requested, admin/corporate/addnew, could not be found.
```

Thats 842. line:

```
throw new Kohana_404_Exception($page, $template);
```

That warning page image:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your `corporate` controller? You have an `addnew` method in there, right? Or are you redirecting this route to another location?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a route setup to handle this particular URL, the default route will NOT handle this. The url "admin/corporate/addnew" is trying to use the admin controller, the corporate action, and an id called 'addnew'.  Im not sure how you have your application structured, but perhaps you need to write a route in your bootstrap.php that looks something like this:

```
Route::set('admin_corporate', 'admin/corporate(/<action>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'corporate',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```

This would need to go BEFORE your default route.